# How to partially filter subset string?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to filter substring from a string. I achieve it like

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'anderstand' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'anderstan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'andersta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'anderst' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understa' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'underst' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'unders' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'under' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand i' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it ye' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes it' 

)
SELECT str FROM (
  SELECT str, 
    STARTS_WITH(LAG(str) OVER(ORDER BY str DESC), str) flag 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE NOT IFNULL(flag, FALSE)
```

Returns only

```
Row str 
1   understand it yes it
2   anderstand
```

Expected result is

```
Row str 
1   understand it yes it
2   anderstand 
3   understand it yes
4   understand
5   understand it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT str FROM (
  SELECT str, STARTS_WITH(prev_str, str) AND  
    ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, r' ')) = ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(prev_str, r' ')) AS flag
  FROM (
    SELECT str, LAG(str) OVER(ORDER BY str DESC) AS prev_str
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
WHERE NOT IFNULL(flag, FALSE)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'anderstand' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'anderstan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'andersta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'anderst' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understa' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'underst' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'unders' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'under' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand i' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it ye' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes it' 
)
```

result is

```
Row str  
1   understand it yes it     
2   understand it yes    
3   understand it    
4   understand   
5   anderstand
```

here I am using space as delimiter - but you can use any by adjusting `r' '` in `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(..., r' ')` . For example you can use `r'\s'` to use any whitespace as a delimiter

Comment: The only problem with the query is that I cannot put any count(*) any where of it, so to make sure if any of this words are repeated. I could do it with previous query

Comment: I don't see any COUNTs in your question - so cannot comment on it. The question as it is asked - is fully answered I think :o)

Comment: Another question just for this would be weird :) Don't make create a new one please. Okay I will create another.

Comment: Up to you- if you feel it is reasonably small extension to current question - update it. If not - post new one. You to decide

Comment: But usually it is not appreciated here when question is extended/changed after proper answer already given

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002013/how-to-partially-filter-subset-string-with-count