# How to partially filter subset string with count?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to filter substring from a string. I achieve it like

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'anderstand' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'anderstan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'andersta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'anderst' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understa' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'underst' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'unders' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'under' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand i' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand i' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it ye' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes it' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes it'
)
```

AND

```
#standardSQL
SELECT str FROM (
  SELECT str, STARTS_WITH(prev_str, str) AND  
    ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, r' ')) = ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(prev_str, r' ')) AS flag
  FROM (
    SELECT str, LAG(str) OVER(ORDER BY str DESC) AS prev_str
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
WHERE NOT IFNULL(flag, FALSE)
```

Returns only

```
Row str  
1   understand it yes it     
2   understand it yes    
3   understand it    
4   understand   
5   anderstand
```

Expected result is

```
Row str                   count
1   understand it yes it   2
2   anderstand             1
3   understand it yes      1
4   understand             1
5   understand it          2
```

Comment: I think you've missed describing logic for counts - I don't think it is obvious here - at least i was not able to catch it just from example you showed

Comment: In the project.dataset.table you will see repeating words. So that I want to know how many times 'str' is repeated in the filter sql (#standardSQL)? So that I will know how many times and 'understand' or 'understand it' is repaated. I am not looking for 'understand it y' @MikhailBerlyant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'anderstand' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'anderstan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'andersta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'anderst' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understa' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'underst' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'unders' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'under' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand i' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand i' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it ye' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes it' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'understand it yes it'
), temp AS (
  SELECT str, COUNT(1) `count`
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY str
)
SELECT str , `count` FROM (
  SELECT str, `count`, STARTS_WITH(prev_str, str) AND  
    ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, r' ')) = ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(prev_str, r' ')) AS flag
  FROM (
    SELECT str, `count`, LAG(str) OVER(ORDER BY str DESC) AS prev_str
    FROM temp
  )
)
WHERE NOT IFNULL(flag, FALSE)
```

with output

```
Row str                     count    
1   understand it yes it    2    
2   understand it yes       1    
3   understand it           2    
4   understand              1    
5   anderstand              1
```

To use above approach - you need just run below query with `project.dataset.table` replaced with reference to your table - like `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT str, COUNT(1) `count`
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY str
)
SELECT str , `count` FROM (
  SELECT str, `count`, STARTS_WITH(prev_str, str) AND  
    ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, r' ')) = ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(prev_str, r' ')) AS flag
  FROM (
    SELECT str, `count`, LAG(str) OVER(ORDER BY str DESC) AS prev_str
    FROM temp
  )
)
WHERE NOT IFNULL(flag, FALSE)
```

Comment: your query works, but when I implement mine, it only gives count. WHERE can I upload my query for you to review? Your previous answers used to work.

Comment: I also tried with subquery with the sql in the OP same. Returms 1 weird.

Comment: I just realized that you have str for 2 of select queriess inside WITH. Maybe it be the problem? Because when I delete them it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry that it is already too much more than my knowledge. This is my sql code. If you can just edit it would be great. I am still trying. https://jsfiddle.net/ox2fbegn/

Comment: as I said you put some alias near understand and anderstand. This is very big SQL for me, I cannot understand all parts. It would have been great, if you just had finalized https://jsfiddle.net/1o4pbhnf/1/

Comment: "extra" alias makes no any difference - I just copy-pasted it from your question. I removed it now, so hopefuly you are less confused

Comment: read again the answer - it has all you need to solve "problem" described in your question!

Comment: I read but I tried to apply same result for me.
I created another question with my real sql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011960/how-to-partially-filter-substring-from-a-table-with-count