# How to partially filter substring from a table with count

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to filter substring from a string. I achieve it like. But I can print count value but it is always 1. I need to print real count number.

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
select  term from(
select LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(textPayload,"Search term:(.*)")) as term  from `log_dataset.backend_*`
where REGEXP_CONTAINS(textPayload, "Search term:.*")=true
)
group by term
order by count(*) desc
), temp AS (
  SELECT term, COUNT(1) `count`
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY term
)
SELECT term , `count` FROM (
  SELECT term, `count`, STARTS_WITH(prev_str, term) AND  
    ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(term, r' ')) = ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(prev_str, r' ')) AS flag
  FROM (
    SELECT term, `count`, LAG(term) OVER(ORDER BY term DESC) AS prev_str
    FROM temp
  )
)
WHERE NOT IFNULL(flag, FALSE)
```

These are a list of terms

```
anderstand
anderstan
andersta
anderst
understand
understan
understa
underst
unders
under
understand i
understand i
understand it
understand it
understand it y
understand it ye
understand it yes
understand it yes it
understand it yes it
```

Desired output is

```
Row str                   count
1   understand it yes it   2
2   anderstand             1
3   understand it yes      1
4   understand             1
5   understand it          2
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired output you can employ a [`GROUP BY`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group-by-clause) statement as follows:

```
SELECT
  str,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
  `project_id.dataset.table`
GROUP BY
  str
```

In addition, the [`LIKE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#comparison_operators) operator can be used to filter the words in the `str` field.